# Banners not visible if user selects More Options in Quancast Choice

Tags: cookies, adsense, cookieconsent

I've implemented Quantcast Choice to gather consent from users on my website. The Quantcast script is included before `</head>` and before any Adsense script. A modal window asking the user to give consent is displayed as expected. No banners are displayed before the user gives consent.

If the user selects "Agree" from the modal window, they get all Adsense banners served as expected.

However, if the user clicks on "More Options" and then "Agree to Selected", no Adsense banners are visible at all. This happens even if the user gives consent to all parts in the modal window (i.e. switches all buttons ON).

The following option in the modal window cannot be switched off by the user:

> **Technically deliver ads or content**
> Your device can receive and send information that allows you to see and interact with ads and content.

My expectation is that if the user gives consent to some or all selected parts, banners should still be visible but they wouldn't be matched to the user's profile and cookies wouldn't be used.

Is my expectation correct? Am I doing something wrongly?

I contacted Quantcast but haven't heard from them yet. I also search online with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a test page by any chance?

Comment: For example this one:
[link](https://www.stcwdirect.com/stcw-courses/basic-safety-training/). 

There is a banner on the right-hand side (visible on large resolution screens).